# How to make this "cropping"/background color changing function more efficient?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm building a web app that requires "detecting" apparels from an image with a white background (or at least from a background with some contrast to it).

I have the following function that's supposed to replace all pixels to white pixels in an image, that differ more than 70% from the pixel in the center of the image in terms of their RGB value.

```
def crop(self, image_data):
    '''"Crops" image by changing all RGB values to [255, 255, 255] if they differ more than
        70% from the pixel in the center of the image.
    '''
    image_data.setflags(write=1)
    height, width, channels = image_data.shape
    new_image_data = np.full((height, width, 3), 255)
    middle_pixel = image_data[(height // 2), (width // 2)]
    middle_pixel_avg = np.mean(middle_pixel)
    difference_limit = middle_pixel_avg * 0.7
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            pixel_avg = np.mean(image_data[row, col])
            if (abs(middle_pixel_avg - pixel_avg) <= difference_limit):
                new_image_data[row, col] = image_data[row, col]
    return new_image_data
```

It's extremely inefficient and takes about 30 seconds to run on a regular image taken on an iPhone. It's also hideous and seems to be a completely wrong way to go about detecting the background of an image.

I'd like to, first of all, know how to make this function of mine more efficient. Secondly, I'd like to know if there are better and more reliable ways to do so?

Here is an example of what this function actually does:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing without loops. For example, `np.mean(image_data, axis=(2))` averages the RGB values for the whole image in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use OpenCV for most of the parts in your function. For example, once you have sampled the intensities in a 3x3 region in the centre (one pixel is probably not representative enough of the 'average' intensity of the fabric), you could use this result to threshold a grey-level version of the image using cv2.threshold() function which a priori should be faster that python loops. Eventually you can use this mask to extract the foreground.

Here is the skeleton of such an implementation:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def remove_background(image):
    """
    Remove the light background from an image of a dark fabric.
    """

    image_intensity = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    assert (image.shape[:2] == image_intensity.shape[:2])
    height, width, channels = image.shape
    dst = np.zeros((height, width, 3))

    center_x = height // 2
    center_y = width // 2

    center_intensity = image_intensity[center_x:center_x+3, center_y:center_y+3]
    center_intensity_avg = np.mean(center_intensity)
    threshold = 3 * center_intensity_avg

    _, thresholded = cv2.threshold(image_intensity, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    result = cv2.add(image, mask)

    return threshold, result

image = cv2.imread("./data/BuGgK.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
threshold, result = remove_background(image)
cv2.imwrite('./out/result.png', result)
```

If some patches within the fabric are below the threshold, they become transparent. To avoid that you can extract the contours and remove the ones that are 'too small' to be a whole cloth. You may also preprocess the images to remove the hanger which create holes (upper part in your image).

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! Do you know if there is any way to make the removed background white, instead of black?

Comment: @nameisxi updated the answer accordingly: the background is now transparent (so in many cases will appear white) :)

Comment: Thanks so much, but unfortunately it needs to be white as in 255, 255, 255. I'm using this function as pre-processing to make my pictures compatible with the model that I use to make predictions, and all of the training images happen to have white backgrounds... I know that the solution won't be as elegant, but is there some sensible way to make the background white? :o

Comment: @nameisxi updated:) to do that, first convert the mask into an 3-channel image, then sum the values of the mask with the original image. disclaimer: not tested with light fabric. hope it helps though :)